# Displaying Bytes array data from Xbee Gateway Receiver Using Python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyserial, xbee

I have been working with Wireless gateway receiver(using Xbee) which is receiving the mentioned below byte array serially

```
7E 00 32 90 00 13 A2 00 41 91 25 D4 FF FE C2 7F 00 01 03 FF 36 00 08 00 00 6B 87 00 2C 52 00 05 DB 00 00 00 00 76 17 00 0C 94 FF 8D 0E FF E4 D6 00 00 00 00 18 88
```

and with the reference of code, I was able to write the code as mentioned below

```
import time
import serial

# Change this serial port to the serial port you are using.
s = serial.Serial('COM6', 9600)

while True:
    packet_ready = s.read()
    print(packet_ready)
    #Read bytes
    #7E 00 32 90 00 13 A2 00 41 91 25 D4 FF FE C2 7F 00 01 03 FF 36 00 08 00 00 6B 87 00 2C 52 00 05 DB 00 00 00 00 76 17 00 0C 94 FF 8D 0E FF E4 D6 00 00 00 00 18 88
    if(ord(packet_ready) == 126):#0x7F HEX Byte
        #while s.inWaiting() < 54:
         #   time.sleep(.001)
        bytes_back = s.read(54)
        if(ord(bytes_back[15]) == 127):#0x7E HEX Byte 
            print('The packet has a data payload: ' + str(ord(bytes_back[14])))
            print('The packet is for sensor type: '+str(ord(bytes_back[22])))
            print('Sensor Number: '+str(ord(bytes_back[16])))
            if(ord(bytes_back[22]) == 8):#0x08 HEX Byte
                print('Sensor Number: '+str(ord(bytes_back[22])))
                rms_x = (((bytes_back[24])<<16) + ((bytes_back[25])<<8) + (bytes_back[26]))/100;
                rms_y = (((bytes_back[27])<<16) + ((bytes_back[28])<<8) + (bytes_back[29]))/100;
                rms_z = (((bytes_back[30])<<16) + ((bytes_back[31])<<8) + (bytes_back[32]))/100;

                max_x = (((bytes_back[33])<<16) + ((bytes_back[34])<<8) + (bytes_back[35]))/100;
                max_y = (((bytes_back[36])<<16) + ((bytes_back[37])<<8) + (bytes_back[38]))/100;
                max_z = (((bytes_back[39])<<16) + ((bytes_back[40])<<8) + (bytes_back[41]))/100;

                min_x = (((bytes_back[42])<<16) + ((bytes_back[43])<<8) + (bytes_back[44]))/100;
                min_y = (((bytes_back[45])<<16) + ((bytes_back[46])<<8) + (bytes_back[47]))/100;
                min_z = (((bytes_back[48])<<16) + ((bytes_back[49])<<8) + (bytes_back[50]))/100;

                print('RMS_X:  ' + str(rms_x))
                print('RMS_Y: ' +str(rms_y))
                print('RMS_Z: '+str(rms_z))
                print('MAX_X: '+str(max_x))
                print('MAX_Y: '+str(max_y))
                print('MAX_Z: '+str(max_z))
                print('MIN_X: '+str(min_x))
                print('MIN_Y: '+str(min_y))
                print('MIN_Z: '+str(min_z))
                print('\n')
```

And the result after working on this code I am getting data as mentioned below

```
b'f'
b'\xc2'
b'b'
b'\xc2'
b'f'
b'\xc6'
b'B'
b'\xf6'
b'f'
b'\xc2'
b'\x08'
b'J'
b'\xfe'
b'f'
b'\xc6'
b'\xe2'
b'\xde'
b'f'
b'B'
b'\xe2'
b'\xc2'
b'f'
b'\xc6'
b'\xe2'
b'\xc2'
b'f'
b'B'
b'\xc2'
b'\xfe'
b'f'
b'\x80'
b'B'
b'\xce'
b'f'
b'\xc2'
b'\xc2'
b'\xc2'
b'f'
b'F'
b'\xc2'
b'\xfe'
b'f'
b'\xc2'
b'\xe2'
b'\xf6'
b'f'
b'\xc6'
b'\xe2'
b'\xc2'
b'f'
b'B'
b'\x08'
b'\xfe'
b'\xfe'
b'f'
b'F'
b'B'
b'\xc2'
b'f'
b'B'
b'\xe2'
b'\xc2'
```

I am not able to understand why my code is not processing further after reading data serially.

Any suggestions on this will be a great help

Comment: *"why my code is not processing further"*: Your first condition `if(ord(packet_ready) == 126):` never becomes `True`, there is no `126` in your recived data.

Comment: Ok so that means I have to first create which the 7E HEX number in decimals called 126 ? But for that case I used ord() unixode function isn't this function helpful?

Comment: *"I used ord()"*: That's ok, but if you **never** receive a byte with `126` == `0x7e` == `'~', `your condition becomes never `True`. Relevant [Python xbee library no output for incoming frames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44849774/7414759)